# $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is not working with console application in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, console-application

When i am trying to run my photoResizer command  like this /var/www/myProject/proted/yiic photoResizer

i am getting this error.

```
PHP Error[8]: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME
in file /var/www/myProject/protected/components/UploadHandler.php at line 190
#0 /var/www/myProject/protected/components/UploadHandler.php(45):  
UploadHandler->get_full_url()
#1 /var/www/myProject/protected/commands/PhotoResizerCommand.php(37):   
UploadHandler->__construct()
#2 /var/www/myProject/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71):    
PhotoResizerCommand->run()
#3 /var/www/myProject/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): 
CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#4 /var/www/myProject/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): 
CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#5 /var/www/myProject/framework/yiic.php(33): CConsoleApplication->run()
#6 /var/www/myProject/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once()
#7 /var/www/myProject/protected/yiic(4): require_once()
```

I need to solve this problem or any alternative to run a php script via command line in yii framework.

Thanks.

Comment: It's your class you get the error in. Try just fixing it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite obviously there's no "server" when running an app from the command line, so you cannot use that variable for anything. Apparently `UploadHandler` is hard coded to expect to be executed in the context of a web request to handle files uploaded within the request (which, you know, makes sense). Since you're not in a web request context, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in config/console.php in components array

```
'request' => array(
    'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
    'baseUrl' => '',
    'scriptUrl' => '',
),
```

and also add urlManager

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```